# Bitwise operation - clear single bit

Tags: c, arduino, bit-manipulation

I was working on some bitwise manipulation on a timer control register in Arduino and I noticed that when I want to clear the bit CS11 in the register TCCR1B then

```
TCCR1B &= (0<<CS11)
```

will not work but the following works perfectly

```
TCCR1B &= ~(1<<CS11)
```

Why does the first (0<<CS11) method not work? I found several pages explaining how to do this and the second method is always mentioned, but I did not find any explanation why the first method does not work. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: think about what bitwise value you get from `(0<<CS11)` - and what happens when you AND it with another value

Comment: `0` shifted by anything is `0`, `AND`-ing with `0` yields `0`.

Comment: `(0<<CS11)` is all 0's

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)

Answer (score 0):

The value of `(0<<CS11)` is `0` (because shifting integer all of whose bits are zero also produces zero), so `TCCR1B &= (0<<CS11)` will make the value of `TCCR1B` zero. (unless some bits of the register are not writable)

On the other hand, `(1<<CS11)` will be an integer one of whose bits is one and the other bits are zero (unless `CS11` is too large or negative) and `~(1<<CS11)` will be an integer one of whose bits is zero and the other bits are one. Therefore `TCCR1B &= ~(1<<CS11)` will clear one bit and leave the other bits unchanged. (unless writing to bits of the register have special meanings)

Comment: Thank you very much - that explains it perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

this short program (which you could write yourself to see what is going on) should explain what is going on.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void printbin(unsigned x)
{
    unsigned mask = 1 << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(mask) - 1);
    for(;mask; mask >>= 1)
    {
        printf("%c", x & mask ? '1' : '0');
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned x = ~0;

    unsigned mask;

    mask = 0 << 5;
    printbin(x); 
    printbin(mask);
    printbin(x & mask);
    printf("\n");

    mask = 1 << 5;
    printbin(x); 
    printbin(mask);
    printbin(x & ~mask);
}
```

and the result:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000

11111111111111111111111111111111
00000000000000000000000000100000
11111111111111111111111111011111
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qnbTce